# Swift If-Statement Array Manipulation Scope

Tags: swift, if-statement, scope

I have a basic array that I'd like to manipulate. It seems that within the brackets of my if statement I can successfully manipulate the array (the right side of the screen shows that value has changed); however, once I leave the if statement, the changes seem to go away (the right side of the screen shows the original value, not the changed one). Thank you for your help!

```
var originalInfo = """
This
Is
A
Test
String
"""

// split string

var SplitInfo = originalInfo.split(separator: "\n")

// Manipulate Array

if SplitInfo[1].hasPrefix("I") == true {
    SplitInfo[1].replacingOccurrences(of: "s", with: "s not")
}

SplitInfo[1]
```

Comment: You are replacing the occurrences but never assigning the new value. ReplacingOccurrence creates a new string, it not edits the given one.

Comment: This demonstrates an advantage of compiled projects over Playgrounds: The compiler clearly warns *"Result of call to 'replacingOccurrences(of:with:options:range:)' is unused"* – Of course reading the documentation would help as well :)

Answer (score 0):

The method `replaceOccurences(of:with:)` returns a String with the new value, so you'll need to assign the new value to the variable

```
SplitInfo[1] = SplitInfo[1].replacingOccurrences(of: "s", with: "s not")
```

Only then will you see the change. If you click on the method and check the Quick Help section in the right pane of Xcode, you'll see

```
Range<String.Index>? = default) -> String
```

the `-> String` means it returns a String, so you'll need to assign that to something.

If you're trying to maintain `String` then divide your string like this

```
var SplitInfo = originalInfo.components(separatedBy: "\n")
```

This will return `[String]` instead of substrings.

Hope this helps.

- Edit based on OP's comment *

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. However, when I make this change I received the error: "Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'String.SubSequence' (aka 'Substring')" How should I resolve this?

Comment: Wrap it in `String(...)` -> SplitInfo[1] = String(SplitInfo[1].replacingOccurrences(of: "s", with: "s not"))

Comment: This does not work. I still receive the error: "Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'String.SubSequence' (aka 'Substring')"

Comment: @Stuart Sorry. I didn't see how you were splitting the string. Use `originalInfo.components(separatedBy: "\n")` instead. That will create `[String]`